# How can I make double bars align vertically over a variable in KaTeX? They are offset currently

Tags: katex

First post!

I am looking to figure out how to align multiple bars over variables in KaTeX.

Currently, they are offset:

[double bars are offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnQcN.png)

This is the partial code where I am trying to implement the double bar:

```
 \$$\bar{\bar{X}}\$$
```

Comment: Please add some code to show your work.

Comment: I added the code!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in KaTeX. I've [reported it](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/3082).

Meanwhile, a workaround is to use `$$\overline{\overline{X}}$$` which renders consistently at least:

[image: KaTeX screenshot]